# Find the following probability and PDF

Tags: probability

An electric current *I* that fluctuates may be considered a random variable evenly distributed in the interval (9,11) amps. If the current goes through a resistance of 2 ohm, the power is $P=2I^2$

Which is the probability of the current to belong to the interval (9,10)? This is the first question.
I don't know how to find it although i want to say 50 porcent for some reason, maybe because it says that is evenly distributed.

Explain why P may be considered a random variable.
This is because I is a random variable.

Find an expression for the PDF of P.
This i don't have any idea of how to do it.

Any hints are welcome. Thanks

Comment: If you don't have any idea what to do, start by writing out the information you are given in mathematical terms. E.g. what does it mean for $I$ to be "evenly distributed in the interval (9,11) amps"? You want a PDF, so blindly write down whatever PDFs you are given. Sometimes, this is enough to figure out the solution, so its a good idea to try this first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general if $9\le a<b\le 11$, the probability that $I$ belongs to $(a,b)$ is $\frac{b-a}{11-9}$. This is what "evenly distributed in $(9,11)$" means. (Some people use the word "uniformly" in place of "evenly".)

For the PDF of $P$, here are two different approaches.

1. Write down the PDF of $I$. Then use the [change of variables formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Application_in_probability) with the transformation $\phi(x) = 2x^2$ to obtain the PDF of $P$.
2. Alternatively, find the CDF of $P$ first, and then take the derivative to obtain the PDF.